# Problems using data from Service to Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I have a service and few controllers. 
The service makes a post request and the controllers suppose to use the data sent back from the server. 
Unfortunately, the RightsMainService.rightsArray returns an array with objects, and every object has only "undefined" fields.
Moreover, the RightsMainService.init is always false.
Not sure where the problem is.

```
    app.service('RightsMainService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$state',  function($http, $rootScope, $state) {

    var self = this;

    this.rightsArray = [];

    this.init = false;

    this.loadRights = function(rightsObject) {
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        };
        $http.post('./server/user.php', $.param(rightsObject), config)
            .success(function(data,status, headers, config) {
                self.rightsArray = data;
                self.init = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('finishLoadingEvent');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, header, config) {
                alert(status + " " + header);
                return;
            });
        $state.go('rights');
    }
}]);



    app.controller('RightsMainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'RightsMainService', function($scope, $rootScope, RightsMainService) {
    var rightsArrayInitialized = false;
    var rightsArray = [];
    (function Initialize(){
        if(RightsMainService.init == false) {
            alert("init");
            $rootScope.$on('finishLoadingEvent', function() {
                rightsArrayInitialized = true;
                rightsArray = RightsMainService.rightsArray;
                for(var key in rightsArray[0]) {
                    alert(rightsArray[key]);
                }
            })
        } else {
            rightsArrayInitialized = true;
            rightsArray = RightsMainService.rightsArray;
            for(var key in rightsArray[0]) {
                alert(rightsArray[key]);
            }
        }
    })();
}]);
```

Please ignore the alerts, they are there for testing purposes

Comment: You need to know what's going on in the 'success' function and moreover, if it's actually loading the data from the server. I would also look at the actual network request/response pair in the browser to see if it contains what is expected.

Comment: Hey, It does loads the correct data and send the broadcast correctly, I've checked it few times already.
I'm concered with the false value of the init variable in the service, which the controllers always sees as false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `$state.go('rights');` before the `$http` has completed. Whole flow process doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Didnt notice the $state.go , it shouldnt have been there O.o